# Chainlink client oracle pricing

Tags: chainlink, oracles

I'm currently utilizing Chainlink Oracle to make API calls. According to the documentation, each call on testnet costs 0.1 Link. However, I'm curious about where I can locate pricing information for using Chainlink Oracle on networks like Optimism, Polygon, or other mainnet networks.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to making API calls, you should use [Chainlink Functions](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/tutorials/api-query-parameters) instead. Billing details for Chainlink Functions are available at the [Official Chainlink Documentation](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/resources/billing).